# Method not found - VanillaChronicle ctor call in net.openhft.chronicle.logger.log4j2.TextVanillaChronicleAppender.createChronicle()

Tags: logging, log4j2, nosuchmethoderror, chronicle

Is there a specific version of OpenHFT Chronicle on which Chronicle Logger for log4j2 v1.0.3 depends?

The only ctor for VanillaChronicle I found was a package visible definition which took param which are different from the method calls in TextVanillaChronicleAppender.

Answer (score 0):

Chronicle-Logger 1.0.x depends on Chronicle-Queue 3.2.x (latest is 3.2.5)